# Get magento 2 custom attribute value

Tags: magento, mage

I am able to display attribute values using the code below BUT if the attribute is empty it just prints out the word "No"

```
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('c_address')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the customer attribute,you can use like this:

```
$customerRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface');
$customer = $customerRepository->getById(1);
$cattrValue = $customer->getCustomAttribute('c_address');
```

To get the product attribute,you can use like this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load('YOUR PRODUCT ID');
echo $product->getAttributeText('your_attribut');
```

Comment: I need to get certain attribute from a product(filtered by product sku) but I get this error when using above code.
**Uncaught Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Exception: Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session**

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is,

```
$customer = $CUSTOMER_OBJECT; // GET customer object
$customer->getCustomAttribute('variable_name')->getValue();
```

But you need to control `$customer->getCustomAttribute('variable_name')` is not NULL

Comment: you just solve my today bigger Problem... Thank you